# Add remove filter an Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, grep

1) I am looking for inbuilt jquery functions which would add/remove/get an item from an array. 
Or a better way to do the same thing I have done below. Although below code works but I feel there should be some better way.

I am not very good at JavaScript so this code may look crappy :)

```
var items = 
[
    {"Selected": false, "Text": "FirstElement", "Value": "1"},
    {"Selected": false, "Text": "SecondElement", "Value": "2"},
    {"Selected": false, "Text": "ThirdElement", "Value": "3"},
    {"Selected": false, "Text": "FourthElement", "Value": "4"}
]

function findItem(items, elementValue) {
    var item = {};

    if(elementValue == undefined || elementValue =="")
        return item;

    var i = $.map(items, function(n,i) { return i; }).length;

    while(i--){
        var temp = items[i].Value;
        if(elementValue == items[i].Value){
            item = {"Text": items[i].Text, "Value": items[i].Value};
        }
    }

    return item;
}

function removeItem(items, elementValue) {
    if(elementValue == undefined || elementValue =="")
        return items;

    var result = $.grep(items, function(e){
        return e.Value != elementValue;
    });

    return result;
}

function addItem(items, elementValue, elementText) {
    if(elementValue == undefined || elementValue =="")
        return items;

    var i = $.map(items, function(n,i) { return i; }).length;
    var x = i;

    var valueExists = false;

    while(i--){
        var temp = items[i].Value;
        if(elementValue == items[i].Value){
            valueExists = true;
        }
    }

    if(!valueExists){
        items[x] = {"Selected": false, "Value": elementValue, "Text": elementText};
    }

//I also need some sorting here on Value
    return items;
}
```

2) I am using

```
var tempItems = Object.assign({}, addItem(items, elementValue, elementText))
```

After adding an item I want the reference in a different temp object as I have to play around with master and filtered list. Is there a way I can add an item and get another instance of returned items.

Probably Object.assign is the root cause I am struggling with add/remove/get items.

Any suggestion is welcomed and appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built in javascript functions (not jquery :):

```
// Finding an item
items.find(function(item) { return item.Value == '3'})

// Removing/filtering out an item (returns a new copy)
items.filter(function(item) { return item.Value !== '3'})
```

To return a new copy of addItem, you could copy items inside the addItems function itself using Object.assign({}, ...).

Comment: All this would work if I would add a new item in a array and return a copy of new array, not reference to the old one or not an object. Could you please give an example how to do that?

Comment: Try:
    `function addItem(items, elementValue, elementText) {
        const itemsCopy = Object([], items); // this is the copy, make modifications and return accordingly`...

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use the native filter method that works on array. It would be something like this:

```js
function findElement(items, elementValue) {
     let result = items.filter(function(item) {
      return item.Value === elementValue; 
     })
     console.log(result); //should output the desired result
    }
```

Comment: I was using some jquery functions but as I said I need a new copy for  that I used Object.assign({}, addItem(items, elementValue, elementText)) after which all that stopped working.